# .NET Console Application Tab Completion

Tags: .net, console

Any ideas on how to implement tab completion for a .NET (C#) Console Application?
And I mean within an application that is run and then loops for user input (like if you run ftp.exe without any arguments), like this:

```
        string line = string.Empty;
        while (line != "exit")
        {
            //do something here
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I know I probably couldn't actually use readline, but I would like to be able to do tab completion at that same point where you retrieve input from the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this code from the Mono project
http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Aug-26.html
I played with it some the other day.
It does a lot of command line editingy, but I don't think it does line completion.

Answer (score 9):

Do a Console.ReadKey().

If you get a Tab, look at what you have in the command buffer, and loop through your available commands. If `someCommand.Name.BeginsWith(currentinput)`, you have a winner, and you can write to screen a list of possible commands.

If *there is only one(TM)* you can substitute it with what the user had typed :)

Comment: using readkey cannot be called in parrallel of readline can it ? so it means you loose readline functionality, and you need to loop over readkey and append / display manually whats input. Readline has history recall functionality with "up" key, you will lose that, or need to recode it entirely using readkey. Best for c14n would be to find a hybrid solution. (like using Async readline ?)

Answer (score 7):

I created a small lib to add this functionality to an app i made:

https://github.com/fjunqueira/hinter

It might not suit your needs, but you can feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 4):

[Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tonerdo/readline is what you need.
great lib available as a nuget from the talented dev tonerdo.

*pasted from the site:*

> ...
> **ReadLine** is a GNU Readline like library built in pure C#
> It can serve as a drop in replacement for the inbuilt `Console.ReadLine()` and brings along with it some of the terminal goodness you get from unix shells, like command history navigation and tab auto completion.
> ...

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)